# auto redirect from paypal to website

Tags: paypal

I have a Buy Now button which works fine but my problem is that I want to return to my website after the transaction is complete. a link or something so that the user will not type again the url or hit the back button of the browser . Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are configuring or editing your button, you have the option under Step 3 to "Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout."

Using this, you can not only take them back to your website, but to a specific landing page. You can also designate different landing pages for each type of transaction.

Hope that helps.

ty

Comment: Note that this will only be an automatic redirect in case the buyer checks out with an existing PayPal account. Guest buyers (who check out without a PayPal account) must click a 'Return to merchant..' button before being redirected to this page.

Comment: I don't understand, what happens if a guest buyer pays but doesn't return to the site by clicking the return link? As the seller, you cannot check that the buyer actually paid in this case, so you won't send him the item(s) he bought either right?

Comment: You receive an email from PayPal when the buyer completes the transaction.

Comment: Right. Sounds unreliable to me though, because emails sometimes don't arrive (happened at least twice to me). Besides, it seems awkward that the website must wait for a click in some email before taking critical actions regarding database record updates. In my mind, what is critical should be executed immediately. I'm surprised things work like that with PayPal standard, I must miss something.

Answer (score 5):

Login to Paypal > Profile > Website Payment Preferences

Within here, enable the auto-return option.
Then enter your return URL - your website.

Please note that Paypal requires you to have some sort of text letting the user know that their transaction has completed.

Hope this helps.
Amarjit